# Missing songs don't add from iCloud Music

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, icloud, music

How can I download some staff, that has `add` link, which don't work properly? I'm trying to redownload, testing on different albums - not help (but not every album has such problem, frequently all tracks are on there places). Not working in mac iTunes, iPhone & iPad.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I suddenly understand... I cannot add these missing files because I have already them in other albums. Maybe it's a big problem for someone, but I just delete albums that are "no so good" and keep "that really rock". So problem solved! Thanks for watching!